# How to look for a newline in input without getline in c

Tags: c, input, getline

I'm trying to create my own "getline" function.

In order to do that I need to find where the next newline character is in the input.

I'm trying to use the pointer `input->_IO_read_ptr` and the function `memchr`.

The issue with this is that `input->_IO_read_ptr` is pointing to NULL. Making this simple program end up in segmentation-fault.

Anyone knows why is this happening and how to fix it?

Thank you!

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    FILE *stream;
    char *looking = NULL;

    stream = stdin;

    looking = memchr((void *)(stream->_IO_read_ptr), '\n', 100);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You appear to be attempting to muck around with the C library internals. Have you reviewed the source code for whatever version it is that you're working with? Why are you trying to re-invent this wheel? What if stream points to stdio or some other serial device?

Comment: You're also going to have problems if the user of your library were to set the stream to non-buffering.

Answer (score 2):

`(stream->_IO_read_ptr)`

The leading _ is a sign unto you that means don't access this.

Your own `getline()` function should be implemented in terms of `getc()`.

Something like

```
ssize_t mygetline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream)
{
    ssize_t i = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getc()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (*n == i + 1) { 
            /* grow buffer */
        }
        lineptr[0][i++] = (char)c;
    }
    lineptr[0][i] = 0;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I know it's pseudo-code, but `n` is an out param that gets updated as the buffer grows.  Similar treatment for `lineptr`.